# How to dynamically copy a table to csv file in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres. I want to write a function that will take a "folder_path" variable as input and write a table's content to that folder as a csv file.

I will be passing different folder paths as input variables to this postgres function.

I tried doing so using copy to function, but it gives lot of errors. It works fine when I hard code the folder_path (file_path) value in copy to function.
eg:

```
COPY Test_csv TO  '/Users/Artificial Intelligence/Test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

`Test_csv` - is my table name
`'/Users/Artificial Intelligence/Test.csv'` - is my folder path

Comment: "*but it gives lot of errors*" - and what **are** those errors? Please **[edit]** you question and add the full source code of the function and the **exact** error messages.  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I am not sure if this would be acceptable or possible for you but there is a Pl/sh language - https://github.com/petere/plsh - which allows you to use linux shell scripts inside PostgreSQL. You would need to create pl/sh function which will call psql - see on github. But you can pass parameters into it and it works well also on 9.6. I use it sometimes for "corner cases".